# Simplifying the error function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, error-function

I have two functions.

$$
y=a\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{t-\mu}{2^{1/2}\sigma}\right), \quad\mu=t_1+c\sigma
$$

I want to simplify $y$ as much as possible. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: There is only one occurrence of each variable and no variable is redundant, so no, it's not possible to simplify it further.

Comment: You could write this in terms of the normal distribution cdf $\Phi(x)$ to remove the $\sqrt 2$